# Unable to chain overloaded assignment operator despite returning a reference

Tags: c++

edit: I have now fixed the issue, I was stupidly deleting the whole bag in my overloaded operator and then trying to insert value into it. I wrote a function to clear the bag without deleting it, and now it works perfectly. Thank you everyone for your help. The original is as follows, in case anyone else ever finds his or herself making the same mistake:

I've seen a lot of other beginners having problems chaining an overloaded = operator, and their problem is almost always forgetting to return a reference in their overloaded operator. However, I believe I am doing so but I am still unable to correctly chain my overloaded + operator.

For example, if I create two MagicBags, mb1 and mb2, then I set

```
mb1 = mb2;
```

this compiles and runs correctly. When I then create a third MagicBag, mb3,

```
mb3 = mb2 = mb1;
```

won't compile, and I get a null pointer in my overloaded operator.

Here is my operator:

```
MagicBag& operator=(const MagicBag& other) {
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
    this->~MagicBag();//clear calling bag
    node<T> * a;//construct a temp node pointer to use as an iterator to loop over original bag and copy its contents
    int tempSize = other.size - 1;
    while (tempSize >= 0) {
        a = other.first;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++) {
            a = a->next;//get my null pointer here
        }
        tempSize--;
        insert(a->value);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

the destructor is

```
~MagicBag() {
    if (first == NULL)
        return;
    if (first->next == NULL) {
        delete(first);
        first = NULL;
        return;
    }
    node<T> * a = first->next;
    while (a != NULL) {
        delete(first);
        first = a;
        a = a->next;
    }
    delete(first);
    first = NULL;
}
```

and the insert function is your standard 4 line insert, I doubt that's the issue. What am I doing wrong? I *believe* my destructor is not the problem, however I am a beginner so it very well may be, and I also believe I am correctly returning a reference in my overloaded operator. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1) commonly cited post, I seem to be following the standard convention for overloading so I'm confused why this works correctly once, but not when chained. I also saw in the linked article from that post, that it's unnecessary to check if the two arguments are the same, however removing that bit doesn't solve the problem. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: The destructor is way too complex that it needs to be, for no readily-apparent reason. That entire hairball appears to be replacable by just a "while (first) { auto p=first; first=first->next; delete p; }"

Comment: The copy constructor refers to `other.size`, but does not update its own `size` member. An obvious fail.

Comment: Off topic: `this->~MagicBag();` scares the bejeebies out of me. You sure you want to do this? It's going to do a lot more than just clear the bag out. It's going to `delete` the bag. Then it looks like `insert` is going to put stuff into the `delete`ed bag. Bad plan. Looks like you need a `clear` function that you call in `=` and the destructor.

Comment: Anyway, this needs a lot more information to be debuggable. [Could you put together a nice minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ichramm It just says "Exception thrown: read access violation.
a was nullptr."

Comment: @user4581301 So this may be my issue, I'm going to try to just make a delete function instead of calling the entire destructor. Thank you for your help, I had originally been creating a copy but removed that when I started hitting snags but accidentally kept the idea of deleting the whole object. Thank you, I believe simply clearing the contents will fix my issue. I am correctly returning a reference though, right?

Comment: That's not a compile-time error, that's a runtime-error.

Comment: If you write `this->~MagicBag();`  then the object lifetime ends; you are not allowed to access any members of the object afterwards.  Your code causes undefined behaviour.  Maybe what you intended to do was to have a function for clearing your container (maybe call it `clear()`), and call that from both the destructor, and from this location.

Comment: @ichramm I believe I know what the issue is now, as the other person noted I was deleting the whole object and then trying to add nodes to it. It was the result of trying a new solution but not thinking clearly. I'm going to write a function that clears the contents of the bag and I believe that should fix everything. Thank you.

Comment: For example maybe the optimizer gets rid of the code `first = NULL;` from the end of the destructor, because there is no legal way `first` can be read after that

Comment: @M.M I believe that is my mistake, I am writing a function to clear the bag without deleting it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @M.M Have in mind that calling the destructor does not end the object's lifetime, it's just another method. The problem is, well, that particular method destroys the object's members.. Calling the destructor is not bad per se, it is just a bad practice. Ben could have written a clear() function and would have suffer of the same problem.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that will return a reference to the object. Get the rest sorted and `return *this;` will do what you want.

Comment: @ichramm no, the destructor ends the object's lifetime. It's special, not just another function. See [basic.life]/1.3 in C++14

Comment: You don't set this->size to zero anywhere.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the reference. It has been very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the code should *compile*! If it gets to a state where it actually runs and you "get a null pointer" it is a different kind of error but compilation is done.

The code itself is riddled with problems. Here are those I spotted (the last one is causing the issue you noticed):

1. Calling the destructor on `this`is **always** wrong. There are a few cases where it is necessary to explicitly call the destructor of an object but all of these involve explicitly constructing an object in a dedicated piece of memory, typically due to use an overloaded `operator new()`. If you really need to use the functionality of the destructor elsewhere, move it into a dedicated function, e.g., a function called `clear()`, and call that from the destructor as well as everywhere else it is needed.
2. The assignment operator has a performance problem: iterating through something like a list is slow. Iterating over [parts of] a list for each element is *very* slow. It is actually easier to iterate over the nodes in the right hand side just once an `insert()` each node's value. That is, the core of assignment could simply be

   ```
   for (node<T>* current = other.first; current; current = current->next) {
       insert(current->value);
   }
   ```

   Since this is the same code as is needed for the copy constructor, I'd actually implement the assignment using the copy&swap idiom:

   ```
   MagicBag& MagicBag::operator= (MagicBag const& other) {
       MagicBag(other).swap(*this);
       return *this;
   }
   ```

   where `swap()` just swaps the contents of all members.
3. It isn't strictly an error but your destructor is way too complex (as a result I can't be sure that it is correct). I don't know all of your class but it seems it could look like this:

   ```
   ~MagicBag() {
       for (node<T>* current = first; current; ) {
           node<T>* tmp = current->next;
           delete current;
           current = tmp;
       }
   }
   ```
4. From the looks of your code, you get a null pointer dereference because neither your destructor nor your assignment operator adjusts `this->size`: the code isn't shown but I *guess* your `insert()` function merely increases `this->size`. As a result, after calling the object's destructor you may have a non-zero `this->size` in the assignment which gets incremented once for each new object. Since the loop in the assignment moves over `other.size` objects it will eventually dereference a null pointer if there are actually fewer nodes than `other.size` implies. That is exactly the case when the right hand side was non-empty when it was assigned to. Assuming you create a `clear()` function, this should set `this->size` to zero (as well as setting `this->first` to a null pointer after `delete`ing the nodes).